# Customize Django Serializer output with to_representation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i want to add Status and place the output of serializer into DATA:

My Model:

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_group_id = models.ForeignKey(UserGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    admin_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_image',blank=True)
```

My Serializer:

```
class UserDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   user = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)
   user_group_id = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)
   class Meta:
      model = UserDetails
      fields = [
         'user',
         'user_group_id',
         'admin_photo',
      ]
      depth = 1

  def to_representation(self, instance):
      data = super(UserDetailSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
      return {
            'STATUS' : 'SUCCESS',
            'DATA' : data 
        }
```

the response i got is this:

```
[
    {
        "DATA": {
            "user": "user1",
            "user_group_id": "Super Admin",
            "admin_photo": "http://www.someurl.com/media/22-black-wallpaper.jpg"
        },
        "STATUS": "SUCCESS"
    },
    {
        "DATA": {
            "user": "user2",
            "user_group_id": "Admin",
            "admin_photo": "http://www.someurl.com/media/fox.jpg"
        },
        "STATUS": "SUCCESS"
    }
]
```

but i want response like this, status are basic text, and i want to put the result from Class meta into DATA

```
{
    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
    "DATA": [
       {
          "user": "user1",
          "user_group_id": "Super Admin",
          "admin_photo": "http://www.someurl.com/media/22-black- 
                          wallpaper.jpg"
       },
       {
          "user": "user2",
          "user_group_id": "Admin",
          "admin_photo": "http://www.someurl.com/media/fox.jpg"
       }
     ]
 }
```

edited
View just using listapiview and use serializer class :

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_vield = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       return UserDetails.objects.all()
```

Comment: First, what do you mean by `STATUS`? Will there be a chance to have ***multiple*** `Status`?

Comment: moreover, pls do add your curresponding view also

Comment: @JPG Its just Success or Failed

Comment: Will there be a chance to have **multiple Status** ina single response?

Comment: @JPG no iust single STATUS, Success or Failed

Comment: Then it's not possible to do in serializer level. So pls do add your views in question

Comment: @JPG  i've added the view,thanks

Comment: I've added one answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it in serializer level, but it's possible to do in view level by overriding the **`list(...)`** method of **`UserListView`**
**Step 1**. Remove **`to_representation`** method from **`UserDetailSerializer`** serializer
**Step 2**. Overriding the **`list()`** method of view as

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_vield = 'id'
    serializer_class = UserDetailSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return UserDetails.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(UserListView, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.data = {"STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DATA": res.data}
        return res
```

Comment: if you dont mind helping me once more,how can i implement this in generics.RetriveAPIView 
because when i use .retreive it doesnt work like .list
example:
        res = super(UserListView, self).retreive(request, *args, **kwargs)
        res.data = {"STATUS": "SUCCESS", "DATA": res.data}
        return res

Comment: You have to override **`retrive(...)`** method instead of `list(..)` method

Comment: great it works, thanks again
looks like im just wrong typing retreive lol